# Handle buttons click event in custom notification in android

Tags: java, android

I have a custom notification with three buttons ("previous", "Play/pause", "Next").
I can catch click event only when there is one button, but with the three buttons i can't know which button of them is clicked. My question is "How to know which button is clicked?"

**my notification code**

```
private void initNotification() 
    {
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        int icon=R.drawable.tmc;
        long when=System.currentTimeMillis();
        Notification notification=new Notification(icon, "The Music Class", when);
        NotificationManager mnNotificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(ns);
        RemoteViews conViews=new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.notification);
        conViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.tmc);
        conViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title, Song_Title);
        notification.contentView=conViews;
        Intent nIntent=new Intent(this,MusicPlayerActivity.class);
        PendingIntent conPendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0,nIntent,0);
        notification.contentIntent=conPendingIntent;

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR; //Do not clear the notification
//        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS; // LED
//        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE; //Vibration
//        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; 


        //this is the intent that is supposed to be called when the button is clicked

        Intent switchIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), switchButtonListener.class);
        PendingIntent pendingSwitchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, switchIntent, 0);
        conViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnPlay, pendingSwitchIntent);
            mnNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    }
```

**switchButtonListener Class**

```
public static class switchButtonListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Here", "I am here");
    }
}
```

in my manifest file

Comment: Use different Intents for each button. Also look at `setAction` if you want one listener for all buttons: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setAction(java.lang.String)

Comment: i can already used but that code  not working properly

Answer (score -2):

Have you check below code

```
RemoteViews conViews=new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.notification);
Button b1=(Button)conViews.findviewbyid(R.id.button1);
Button b2=(Button)conViews.findviewbyid(R.id.button2);
Button b3=(Button)conViews.findviewbyid(R.id.button3);

b1.setonclicklistner(new ...){

onclick(View v){
  //    b1 click listner
}
}
```

same as other button click...
i hope this will help you.....

Comment: i can used your code but that generate error "Add cast to conViews"